# How to create a new contentversion(pdf) using the existing contentversion(word) version data

Tags: apex, contentversion, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I want to generate the pdf file using word document. I was trying to create the new contentversion(pdf) using the existing contentversion(word) versiondata. However, the pdf is not opening after creating it. Could anyone throw some light on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do this in Salesforce. You would need software capable of transforming the Word data into PDF data, which are two entirely different, and incompatible, formats. This can't be done in Apex, and probably can't easily be done in JavaScript, either, in case you were tempted to write a client-based conversion software.

Comment: Thank you for confirming @sfdxfox. I realized that it is not possible with apex and includes lot of code and not easy in javascript :(